# Restify: Passing User Data

Tags: node.js, user-data

I am writing service using NodeJS + Restify. I have split each actual service into separate file (what, I assume, everyone is doing). They all are going to be using mysql database so I thought I could open a single connection to database which could be used by each service rather than opening connections every time a request is done.

The problem is that I don't seem to find a way to pass user data. By *user data* I mean any custom data that would be accessible by every service callbacked by the server.

Answer (score 2):

I primarily use NodeJS + Express, but having looked through some of the documentation of Restify, I believe you could use the authorization parser (under Bundled Plugins on their site: [click here to go there)](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/#Bundled-Plugins)

I think that would be the most basic way to pass user data. 
I haven't tested it but, I believe you'd just add this to use it:

```
server.use(restify.authorizationParser());
```

You could then access the user data with:

```
//This is based on the structure of req.authorization in the documentation.
req.authorization.basic.user
```

I believe you could set new user data (when the user logs in or something) like:

```
 req.authorization.id = 'id'
```

Comment: Interesting. Not exactly what I was asking for but answered one of my other problems :D